# Deep linking from an external link to React PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make the user access to the installed PWA on his phone through an external link that they click on, outside the PWA. How can I do so?
I have tried adding intent_filters, scope_url, and start_url in my manifest.Json as below, but it does not work for me.

[image: manifest.json]

can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

use scope tag, not scope_url:

https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#nav-scope

Also, scope may depends on start_url and/or/neither manifest url :

https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#scope-member